# How do I update a react.js component with a promise return ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I developed a simple promise which returns a value. This value must update the state of the react component. But it doesn't work because the component function setState isn't available in the promise.then() scope.

```
login_account(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function (session_token) {
                return this.setState({token: session_token});
            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which provide lexical scoping

```
login_account(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((session_token) => {
            return this.setState({token: session_token});
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is few ways. If you able to use ES6 syntax - use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), they are don't changing the scope.

If you not able to use ES6 syntax, just create a dump of `this` contex above. Like this:

```
var self = this;    
login_account(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function (session_token) {
       return self.setState({token: session_token});
});
```

Other way, to use callback function and change the context using native JavaScript function - `bind` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)). Probably it will looks like this one:

```
login_account(this.state.email, this.state.password)
   .then(callbackFunction.bind(this, session_token));
```